# count the total number of 1's in integers from 1 to N

Tags: algorithm, math

**Problem Statement:**

Given an integer n, count the total number of digit 1 appearing in all non-negative integers less than or equal to n.

For example:
Given n = 13,
Return 6, because digit 1 occurred in the following numbers: 1, 10, 11, 12, 13.

**Efficient Solution:**

```
int countDigitOne(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    int q = n, x = 1, ans = 0;
    do {
        int digit = q % 10;
        q /= 10;
        ans += q * x;
        if (digit == 1) ans += n % x + 1;
        if (digit >  1) ans += x;
        x *= 10;
    } while (q > 0);
    return ans;
}
```

**My question:**

I found the solution to the question in one of the forums, I am finding it hard to comprehend the solution. I understand its a very simple one but please help me by explaining in detail.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Try to observe the pattern here**

Consider N = 2196, which has 4 digits having place values ones, tens, hundreds and thousands.

Now, try to observe the pattern:

```
Numbers having 1 at ones position
1  11  21  31  41  51  ...

Numbers having 1 at tens position
10  110  210  310  ...
11  111  211  311  ...
......................
19  119  219  319  ...

Numbers having 1 at hundreds position
100  1100  2100  ...
101  1101  2101  ...
102  1102  2102  ...
....................
199  1199  2199  ...
```

Can you see a cluster of 1 number with a time period of 10 in ones,
a cluster of 10 numbers with a time period of 100 in tens and a cluster of 100 numbers with a time period of 1000 in hundreds?
So, our final answer would be `Summation of (N / Time Period) * Cluster Size`
But, be careful with the last case, 
if `N % Time Period != 0`, There is one more cluster which will not be complete.
Try to figure that out by taking N = 2196.
From the above analysis:

Here is the C++ code

```
int solve(int A){
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= A; i *= 10){
        // i is cluster size.
        // temp is time period.
        int temp = i * 10;
        // min(max(A%temp-i+1, 0), i) -> this part is going to take care 
        // of extra last cluster.
        ans += ((A/temp) * i) + min(max(A%temp-i+1, 0), i);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So, in the code you included in your question, `digit` is moving through the digits from right to left and `q` corresponds with how many `x`s, an increasing power of ten, are in the number. Each cycle in the while loop counts how many ones are in that position. Let's look at an example:

```
n     => 131
digit =>  1,  3,  1
q     => 13,  1,  0
x     =>  1, 10,100

q * x      => 13*1
// there are 13 ones in the 10^0 position from 0 to 130 (13 counts of 10)

digit == 1 => n % 1 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
// there is 1 one in the 10^0 position from 131 to 131 
   (the remainder for the counts of 10)

---

q * x      => 1*10
// there are 10 ones in the 10^1 position from 0 to 100 (1 count of 100): 10 to 19

digit == 3 => x = 10
// there are 10 ones in the 10^1 position from 101 to 131: 110 to 119
   (the remainder for the counts of 100)

---

q * x      => 0*100
// there are 0 ones in the 10^2 position from 0 to 0 (0 counts of 1000)

digit == 1 => n % 100 + 1 = 31 + 1
// there are 32 ones in the 10^2 position from 0 to 131
   (the remainder for the counts of 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach this: Suppose that `n < 10^k`, i.e. `n` can be represented by `k` decimal digits. Let's try to construct all positive numbers that have `k` or less decimal digits, with `1`s in them.
There are `2^k` possibilities to place `1`s in some of the `k` bits.

For each choice of `1` placements, we can easily count all positive numbers that have maximum of `k` digits, and are smaller than `n`.

For example, all numbers that match the pattern `yxxx1xx11x`, where each `x` can be `0` or `2-9`, and `y` is `2-9`. Notice the special `y` there, because if `y==0`, the `x` after it is not allowed to be zero. There are `8 * 9^6` possibilities. So this pattern contributes `3 * 8 * 9^6` to the total count, because each such number contains 3 `1`'s.

This gets a little bit complicated, because we need to restrict the number to those that are smaller or equal to `n`. This means that not every combination of `y` and `x`s are valid. For instance, if `n=6239914230`, then `y<=6`, and for `y<6`, the first `x` must be at most 2, etc...